# CMake linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to transfer an old side project to CMake. Previously it used a Makefile with custom variables, defines and etc. I specified the same flags to compile various configurations. I did it this way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(wise_RK)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(SOURCES main.cpp devices/RK.cpp LogWriter/LogWriter.cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DIMA -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF '$@.d'")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

include_directories(
    structs
    devices
    LogWriter
    /home/data/lib/wise_versioning
    /home/data/lib/wisenet
    /home/data/lib/wise_log
    /home/data/lib/wise_rs_device
    /home/data/lib/json
)

# wise_rs_device
add_library(wise_rs_device STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(wise_rs_device PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/data/lib/wise_rs_device/libwise_rs_device.a"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/home/data/lib/wise_rs_device/"
)

# wisenet
add_library(wisenet STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(wisenet PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/data/lib/wisenet/libwise_net_rs485.so"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/home/data/lib/wisenet/"
)

#wise_log
add_library(wise_log STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(wise_log PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/data/lib/wise_log/Release/GNU-Linux/libwise_log.so"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/home/data/lib/wise_log/"
)

add_executable(wise_rk ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(wise_rk PRIVATE wise_rs_device wisenet wise_log)

add_definitions(-DSOME_IMPORTANT_DEFINITION)
```

`-D` is define of various configurations.

In the Makefile, the list of project object files (not libraries) involved in the assembly was like this:

```
OBJECTS:=$(shell find * -type f -name "*.cpp" | sed "s/\.cpp/\.o /" | sort)
DEPENDS:=$(addprefix build/$(CONF)/, ${OBJECTS:.o=.o.d})
-include ${DEPENDS}
```

When I built my CMake:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -DIMA -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF '$@.d'   CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/devices/RK.cpp.o CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/LogWriter/LogWriter.cpp.o  -o wise_rk -rdynamic /home/data/lib/wise_rs_device/libwise_rs_device.a /home/data/lib/wisenet/libwise_net_rs485.so /home/data/lib/wise_log/Release/GNU-Linux/libwise_log.so 
c++: warning: CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/main.cpp.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: warning: CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/devices/RK.cpp.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: warning: CMakeFiles/wise_rk.dir/LogWriter/LogWriter.cpp.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: warning: /home/data/lib/wise_rs_device/libwise_rs_device.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: warning: /home/data/lib/wisenet/libwise_net_rs485.so: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: warning: /home/data/lib/wise_log/Release/GNU-Linux/libwise_log.so: linker input file unused because linking not done
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/anzipex/Downloads/wise_RK/build'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/anzipex/Downloads/wise_RK/build/CMakeFiles  1 2 3
[100%] Built target wise_rk
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anzipex/Downloads/wise_RK/build'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/anzipex/Downloads/wise_RK/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

I do not know what to do next to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: My CMakeLists.txt file: https://pastebin.com/mFw3rkhW

Comment: Your `libwise*.so` libraries are not STATIC

Comment: What is the purpose of  `'$@.d'`? It this supposed to translate to `wise_rk.d` or similar? I'm not sure that is happening correctly when running with CMake? Perhaps, try running with that removed. And, as commented, decide whether `wisenet` and `wise_log` libraries should be static or shared.

Comment: Remove the `-c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF '$@.d'` part from your `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed all the `.so` libs to `SHARED`. And also removed part of flags `-c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF '$@.d'` like @Botje wrote. Seems like project built.